# C2296: '-' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned int

Tags: c++, string

When I try to extract a substring from another, this error occurs. I think that it's coming from this operation `strApp.length - 2` that I'm trying to make, but I cannot find how to fix it.

Error message:

> C2296: '-' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned int (__thiscall
>   std::basic_string,std::allocator>::*
>   )(void) throw()

Related code:

```
this->appName = strApp.substr(strApp.substr(0, strApp.length - 2).find_last_of("\\") + 1, strApp.length);
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please ?

Comment: @Paranaix That’s maybe a bit strong. We had *most* questions already, but searching for this particular one isn’t trivial.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No I dont think so: he posted the same question (nearly the same formulations, copy pasta...) just some minutes ago; he got plenty of comments and answeres explaining his mistake. Now he has created a new account ! and even managed to add yet more erros. Sorry but it seems to me that some people are unable to accept help.

Comment: @Paranaix Oh, that changes things. But [I can’t find the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=newest&pageSize=30).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think he deleted the question, So my assumptation that he created a new account might be wrong though

Comment: Just for the record, it’s also not recently (~ last 2 hours) deleted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I definitely commented on a question with the exact same line of code and error today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658612/c3867-stdbasic-stringchar-stdchar-traitschar-stdallocatorcharlen

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the follow-up. Bizarre that the question doesn’t appear in the [list of recently deleted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=). Maybe that list doesn’t contain questions deleted by their owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `strApp` is a `std::string`, the `length` member is a function, so you need to call it to get the length of the string. To call a function, you must place parentheses after the function name:

```
strApp.length()
```

Since the `length` function doesn't take any parameters, the parentheses are empty.